# PHP Ver 7 - Undefined index: eating - Post method

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I was making a simple form for getting data stored into variable.

**My HTML Code:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="result.php">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="eat" class ="control-label col-md-3">Eating:</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="eating" placeholder="Hours Spent Eating Everyday">
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
<center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Let's Know What You DID!</button></center>
</div>
```

**MY PHP Code:**

```
<?php 
$eat = $_POST["eating"];
?>
```

**Error I'm Getting:**

> Notice: Undefined index: eating
>   Notice: Undefined variable: eating
>   Please help me out, I am using WAMP with Version 7 of PHP.

Comment: How is that form submitted?

Comment: `<div class="col-md-12">
      <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Let's Know What You DID!</button></center>
     </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="eating" placeholder="Hours Spent Eating Everyday" name="eating">
```

In php

```
If(isset($_POST["eating"])){
 $eating = $_POST["eating"];
}
```

Comment: Alright, fixed all my errors. Thanks alot!

Comment: I am getting error at this line: $totalhours = $eating; and the error is:  Undefined variable: eating

Comment: @AviThour This is likely because you aren't entering a value for eating when the form is being submitted. This means the variable isn't set because of the is set check.

Comment: @Ben I am entering a value for sure and i don't know why its error.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" id="eating" placeholder="Hours Spent Eating Everyday">
```

to

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="eating" placeholder="Hours Spent Eating Everyday">
```

POST is referencing the name, not the ID.

Comment: That was well spotted!

Comment: Still, same error.

Comment: I also dont see a submit button, you might want to add that to your answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly Edited the main post.

Comment: Are you including the submit button within the form code? It needs to be before `</form>`

Comment: @Ben Lol yes, i am.

Comment: Its not me with the question. @AviThour all inputs must be between the `<form>...</form>` including the submit button

Comment: Also make sure you're actually inputting a value when your testing it. You're not checking if the value is set before using it in your PHP code so if it is left blank then it isn't going to work.